# Credit Card MMYY Format Future and Past Dates

Tags: sql

I'm currently working on a query where the Credit Card Date is in a MM/YY format. I'm looking to capture where the expiration date has passed or will pass in the next 30days (next month). I'm new to SQL so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Date/time functionality is too often far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: Show your attempt and what error you got.

Comment: We need a lot more information than that.  What DBMS are you using? (SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL? Something else?)  What datatype is your date in?  Do you have any sample data and desired results?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you used?

Comment: Simply cast it as a DATE (after adding `01` as day)

Comment: My apologies, I just signed up. I'm using SQL Server, I've tried: WHERE ZZCCEXPDATE < DATEADD(mm,GETDATE(),1) AND ZZCCEXPDATE > GETDATE()

Comment: `WHERE CCExpire = (RIGHT('00' + CAST(MONTH(DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR), 2) 
+ RIGHT(CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(mm, 1, GETDATE())) AS VARCHAR), 2))`

Comment: This query would be much easier if the expiration date was stored properly - expiration dates should be stored as 1) an actual date type and 2) as an exclusive upper bound (the first date the card is no longer valid - ie the first date of July when the card expires "in June").

Answer (score 0):

This code will produce in `@check` variable 0 if the card is valid, 1 if the card is already expired and 2 if the card will expire in a month.

```
SET @exp_date = '05/13';

SELECT STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('01/',@exp_date),'%d/%m/%Y') INTO @new_date;

SET @new_date = DATE_ADD(@new_date, INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
SET @new_date = DATE_SUB(@new_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);

SET @future = DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

IF @new_date > @future THEN SET @check = 0;
ELSEIF @new_date < NOW() THEN SET @check = 1;
ELSEIF @new_date > @future THEN SET @check = 2;
END IF;
```

This should work in MySQL.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth reply, I'm using SQL Server currently. Would this work for both?

Comment: I 'm trying to check it trough SQL Fiddle but it refuse to create a dummy table to proceed.

Comment: I hope you meant Microsoft SQL Server .... you have to find something like STR_TO_DATE() and DATE_ADD() in MS SQL dialect...

Answer (score 0):

if the initial size of your variable is:  MM/YY
you can use sometihng like this to compare your date (12/16 sample), considering the beginning of the next month:

```
DECLARE @ZZCCEXPDATE NVARCHAR(5) = '12/16' 
DECLARE @dtDate datetime = CONVERT(datetime,'01/' + @ZZCCEXPDATE, 3) 
SELECT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,CONVERT(datetime,'01/' + @ZZCCEXPDATE, 3))+1,0)
```

so in the where clause you can use:

```
..DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,CONVERT(datetime,'01/' + @ZZCCEXPDATE, 3))+1,0)
```

Comment: dates/times in SQL Server can have at least 6 decimal places of fractional seconds, so this is doomed to failure in several ways.

Comment: thanks, now I consider the beginning of the next month